# Reorder Zipped Matrix Elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I have two matching size matrices in a spreadsheet of variable size, one with data items and another flagging items enabled for processing. After zipping the items they are not in a convenient order to process. How are items zipped so I have item and enable together?

Expecting to just `zipper = zip(output, doit)` but it failed badly as shown in output.

Expected output and zipped matrices are shown below.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
    ['Number', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2'],
    [2, 40, 30],
    [3, 40, 25],
    [4, 50, 30],
    [5, 30, 10],
]
enabled = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
]

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)
output = []
for i, row in enumerate(ws['B1:C5']):
    output.append([])
    for cell in row:
        output[i].append(cell.value)

for row in enabled:
    ws.append(row)
doit = []
for i, row in enumerate(ws['A6:B10']):
    doit.append([])
    for cell in row:
        doit[i].append(cell.value)

zipper = zip(output, doit)
print(zipper)

for i in range(len(output[0])):
    print(">>Do column")
    for j in range(len(output)):
        if doit[j][i]:
            print(output[j][i])
```

**Output**

```
[([u'Batch 1', u'Batch 2'], [0, 0]), ([40, 30], [0, 1]), ([40, 25], [1, 1]), ([50, 30], [0, 0]), ([30, 10], [0, 1])]
>>Do column
40
>>Do column
30
25
10
```

I was expecting zipper to look like:

```
[
[(0, u'Batch 1'), (0, u'Batch 2')]
[(0, 40), (1, 30)]
[(1, 40), (1, 25)]
[(0, 50), (0, 30)]
[(0, 30), (1, 10)]
]
```

No success with:

```
# Flatten
zipper = zip(sum(output, []), sum(doit, []))
# Reassemble array
y = zip(*[iter(zipper)]*2)
print(list(y))
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code to what are you trying to `zip` and what would you like as outcome?

Comment: Updated. This is about the minimum to show the matrices in the spreadsheet and the ineffective zip outcome. Feel free to edit question as long as it allows processing enabled cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
zipper = [[(a, c), (b, d)] for [a, b], [c, d] in zip(output, doit)]
inverse_zipper = [[(c, a), (d, b)] for [a, b], [c, d] in zip(output, doit)]
```

as a replacement to your old line

```
zipper = zip(output, doit)
```

---

**standard types**

`[]` indicates a `list` and `()` a `tuple`. the docs for python types are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html). the main difference is that tuples are immutable. here i just respected you desired output

---

**list comprehension**

```
zipper = [[(a, c), (b, d)] for [a, b], [c, d] in zip(output, doit)]
```

is equivalent to

```
zipper = []
for [a, b], [c, d] in zip(output, doit):
    zipper.append([(a, c), (b, d)])
```

---

**unpacking**

unpacking is sort of a quick assignment. `a, b = [4,7]` is equivalent to

```
some_list = [4,7]
a = some_list[0]
b = some_list[1]
```

both assign 4 to a and 7 to b

you know the output of `zip(output, doit)` is `[([u'Batch 1', u'Batch 2'], [0, 0]), ([40, 30], [0, 1]), ([40, 25], [1, 1]), ([50, 30], [0, 0]), ([30, 10], [0, 1])]`
so if you do `for row in zip(output, doit):`, `row` will be in the form of `([40, 30], [0, 1])` which can be unpacked as `[a, b], [c, d]`
you can make that assignment directly in your for statement which gives `for [a, b], [c, d] in zip(output, doit)`

Comment: Very simple. Can you explain how to implement it? I assume this replaces all of the code after the `zipper =` but I don't understand how to get the required output and if it generates or requires the expected zipper.

Comment: The solution is nice. I'm old time basic/fortran/pascal/cobol. I've been through a few tutorials and python Lists, Arrays, Tuples and Dictionaries are still bastardised arrays to me. I understand the `zipper =` and `zip(output, doit)` part of the line but not the rest. I get the idea it is for each row reorder the zip output. Can you explain how it works? I'm not clear on the difference between [] and () either.

Comment: My example reversed the zip elements and your answer doesn't. I actually need ... `zip(doit, output)`...

Comment: i tried to explain simply. if it's still obscure, don't hesitate to ask again

Comment: Very explicit answer which you pulled together at the end and supported with a very useful reference. Thanks for the fishing lesson!

Comment: Caught a fish already! This is better because it supports _variable size matrices_: `zipper = [(zip(doit[j], output[j])) for j in range(len(output))]`

Comment: the `for ... in` syntax already does that, but the range version allows some funny stuff `for … in` can't provide